# PHP: Most performant way to do bitwise OR

Tags: php, performance

I have two bit strings, each four bits long.

```
e.g.,
$role1BitString = '1010';
$role2BitString = '1001';
```

I want to OR them, so that in this case the result would be:

```
$bitString = '1011';
```

Here is the code that I have, but it calls substr eight times.

```
$selectBit = (substr($role1BitString, RBAC::SELECT_BIT, 1) == '1' || substr($role2BitString, RBAC::SELECT_BIT, 1) == '1') ? '1' : '0' ;
$insertBit = (substr($role1BitString, RBAC::INSERT_BIT, 1) == '1' || substr($role2BitString, RBAC::INSERT_BIT, 1) == '1') ? '1' : '0' ;
$updateBit = (substr($role1BitString, RBAC::UPDATE_BIT, 1) == '1' || substr($role2BitString, RBAC::UPDATE_BIT, 1) == '1') ? '1' : '0' ;
$deleteBit = (substr($role1BitString, RBAC::DELETE_BIT, 1) == '1' || substr($role2BitString, RBAC::DELETE_BIT, 1) == '1') ? '1' : '0' ;
$bitString = $selectBit . $insertBit . $updateBit . $deleteBit;
```

This code will be executed dozens of times with every user operation.  What is the most performant way of doing this?

Comment: What about using *actual bytes* instead of strings containing ones and zeroes? `$role1BitString = 10; $role2BitString = 9;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using an actual int with bitshifting and using the bitwise or operation

use `intval($string, 2)`  to convert your binary string to an int and then use `|` to do the operation

Comment: Measured in seconds of runtime, my solution was averaging a detectable runtime of about .000977.  This solution is virtually never registering a detectable runtime at all.  My method was to subtract end time in microseconds from a start time in microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Just use PHP's [bitwise operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) `|`:

```
$bitString = $role1BitString | $role2BitString;
```

Comment: While this will work, it won't result in the correct value for all cases.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams and what would be the reason/cases for this?

Comment: Numerals in strings are always interpreted as decimal. It works with the OP's numbers from sheer dumb luck.